# Get field value and use as variable in php

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, advanced-custom-fields

I have code below. Product field "position" has a value of 52 on 50% of the products. The other 50% have value 100. I want to set a value in the code below to be this variable. At the end of the code you see I have inserted variable $position, but it's not working. Next to that, the generated text doesn't seem to use the font I specified. Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
function add_frontend_fields(){
        global $product;
        $product_id = $product->get_id();
        $position = get_field('position');  
        }


function generate_image(){
        $image = $_POST['image'];
        $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];
        $position = $_POST['position'];
        $text = wc_clean($_POST['poster_text']);
        $textlower = wc_clean($_POST['poster_textlower']);
        $time = wc_clean($_POST['datetime']);
        $location = wc_clean($_POST['location']);
        $file_url = $this->_create_image($image, $text, $textlower, $time, $location, $product_id);
        wp_send_json_success(array('file' => $file_url));
    }


function _create_image( $virtualsky, $text, $textlower, $time, $location, $product_id ) {
        $upload_dir  = $this->get_upload_folder();
        $filename        = 'image.png';
        $hashed_filename = md5( $filename . microtime() ) . '_' . $filename;
        $file_path = $upload_dir[0].$hashed_filename;
        $file_url = $upload_dir[1].$hashed_filename;

        $img             = str_replace( 'data:image/png;base64,', '', $virtualsky );
        $img             = str_replace( ' ', '+', $img );
        $decoded         = base64_decode( $img );



        $line1 = $text;
        $line2 = $textlower;
        //$line2 = "The sky above {$location} on ".date('F d, Y', strtotime($time)).' at '.date('H:i', strtotime($time));;

        file_put_contents( $file_path, $decoded );



        $template = plugin_dir_path( WOO_VIRTUALSKY_GENERATOR_FILE ).'public/images/template.jpg';

        if(!empty($product_id)){
            $template_id =  get_field('poster_template', $product_id);
            if($template_id){
                $template_file = get_attached_file($template_id);
                if($template_file){
                    $template = $template_file; 
                }
            }
        }

        $template = imagecreatefromjpeg($template);

        $font_family = plugin_dir_url( WOO_VIRTUALSKY_GENERATOR_FILE ).'public/lib/fonts/AmaticSC-Regular.ttf';
        imageloadfont ($font_family); 

        $color = imagecolorallocate($template, 0, 0, 0);
        $fontSize = '22';
        $width1 = imagefontwidth($fontSize) * strlen($line1);
        $width2 = imagefontwidth($fontSize) * strlen($line2);
        $height1 = imagefontheight($fontSize);
        $img_w = 960;
        $height = 1050;

        imagestring ($template,$fontSize,($img_w/2)-($width1/2), $height, $line1, $color);

        imagestring ($template,$fontSize,($img_w/2)-($width2/2), $height+$height1+10, $line2, $color);


        $sky = imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
        imagecopy($template, $sky, 148, $position, 0, 0, 660, 660);
        unlink($file_path);
        imagejpeg($template,$file_path);
        imagedestroy($template);
        return $file_url;   

    }
```

Comment: Maybe `$position = get_field('position');` should include the `$product_id` set on previous line? I.e `$position = get_field('position', $product_id);`

Comment: And the issue with the font should probably be asked as a separate question.